# How do I prevent Turbine from writing to my console?

Tags: unit-testing, turbine

That's the question.  I'm trying to write some unit tests against it and want to disable its logging so I can more easily find my test output.  I tried turning off everything I could think of with the logger (log4j), and it keeps writing to my console.

Answer (score 0):

What system are you using?

In *nix you can eliminate output by piping to /dev/null:

```
turbine &> /dev/null
```

or to only pipe errors to a specific file use:

```
turbine 2> turbineOutput
```

So, **1>** pipes only stdout, **2>** pipes stderr, **&>** pipes everything.

Or, maybe I don't know quite what you're asking?